# I get "cannot resolve method .getEntity()" in my Android?

Tags: android

I write the code below in JsonArrayRequest :

```
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I get "EntityUtils" by adding library useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy', but I get "cannot resolve method .getEntity()" in my Android ? How to solve the problem ?

Below is part of my Android code :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, HttpUrl,null,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I can't add ".getEntity()" in my code and it show "can't resolve method .getEntity() ...

Comment: Add your EntityUtils class here

Comment: How are you adding the lib ?

Comment: Sorry, Rutvik Bhatt ! Add EntityUtils class where ?

Comment: by adding useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' in gradle android{}

Comment: Hi, can you show your error log ? Also can you add a bit more code like how and where are you creating your `response` variable and what is its data type ?

Comment: I add code already, it's not error log, I just can't add ".getEntity()" in my code and it show "can't resolve method .getEntity() ...

Comment: since your response is of `JSONObject` type and `JSONObject` class doesn't have a `getEntity()` method that is why it is giving you an error. Are you sure you want `JSONObject` here and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between two libraries. You said you are using `org.apache.http.legacy` but instead it looks like you are using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) library.

Now in your `onResponse()` method your `response`object is of `JSONObject` which doesn't have that `getEntity()` method. It looks you are just trying to get response as a string.

To do that just replace

```
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

with

```
 String jsonString = response.toString();
```

If you were actually using `org.apache.http.legacy` then your response would have been of `HttpResponse` type from that library only then your `response` object would have had the `getEntity()` method.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks ! I really appreciate it !